# How many license keys can i retrive or use for a single product on a MSDN Volume License Subscription

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Before i go and install Windows 7 RTM i wanted to know how many keys are availble from a Single MSDN Volumne License Subsription?  Are there any limits?

Also, when Win7 is offially released do i need to change the RTM key?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask Microsoft?

Comment: Indeed. You pay MS good money for MDSN or TechNet, if you have questions about it, just ask them.

Answer (score 3):

See official explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MSDN software is for development and test only (with the exception of one instance of Office for MSDN editions including Office), and usually limited to 10 instances.

In the past MSDN activating keys have been documented as limited to 10 activations, but appears to be possible to get more (or the counts reset). But then I've never pushed the limit.

Normal retail keys don't have a hard activation limit, its more of a limit on the rate of activations.